# Conditions for title for tag a in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to create the conditions, if tag `a` (links)  has something in the `title` do nothing, else if you do not have something description to use the script..

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
if ( $('a').attr('title') == 'on any text' ) {
    // do this
} else {
    // do that
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so.. do you want to check if the anchor tag have title or not ? am i right ?
then here is a solution for that..

```
if($('a').attr('title'))
  alert($('a').attr('title'));
else
  alert('There is no title');
```

Comment: People can downvote for any reason they want - especially when the original question doesn't meet the site guidelines. If you want to rant about it, leave a comment.

Comment: ok. i understand. but its good when they also post the reason for that like you did! :)